# Comparing a char with multiple characters

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, char, boolean

```
for(int j=0 ; j<str.length() ; j++) {
    if(char[j]==(a||e||i||o||u))
        count++;
}
```

I know the result of `(a||e||i||o||u)` is a Boolean so can't compare but how can we check for multiple character presence?

Comment: Use `String.contains()`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is not doing what you want. Please use a stack `switch` statement:

```
for(int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++)
     switch(str.charAt(j)) {
         case 'a':
         case 'e':
         case 'i':
         case 'o':
         case 'u':
             count++;
     }
```

Or, since I'm a *regex enthusiast*, here's an approach using **regular expressions**! :)

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[aeiou]").matcher(str);
while(matcher.find())
    count++;
```

<strike>*There was a mistake in this code fixed later on, [thanks to user2980077](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24977783/comparing-a-char-with-multiple-characters/24977865?noredirect=1#comment38828914_24977865)*</strike>

Comment: This is the more faster way. By the way, the question is a trifle.

Comment: @Unihedron Honestly, I wasn't sure if a `switch` statement jumped to the end without the explicit `default:` case if it doesn't find a matching case - as a `switch` is still nothing more than an organized `goto`. If that's the case, then I guess it didn't fix an error, but at least I indented it to be pretty :D

Answer (score 4):

One more for the clever regex department:

```
count = str.replaceAll("[^aeiou]","").length();
```

Comment: @Unihedron Yes, if `count` could be nonzero before the questioner's code and it was his intent to add to what was already there, `+=` is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use `String.contains()` and add every searched char into a String.

```
private static final String SEARCH = "aeiou";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] chars = new char[]{'a', 'b', 'A'};
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        if (SEARCH.contains((chars[i] + "").toLowerCase())) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Output is 2. (Code surely can be optimized)

This has three benefits:

1. It is much easier to add new chars to look for.
2. This code is case insensitive. (remove the `toLowerCase()` method call to make it case sensitive)
3. You avoid "long" if/else or switch/case blocks.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the classes you can try with regex or simple String

```
String s = "aeiouaeiou";//string to count
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

  //One method
  if ("aeiou".indexOf( s.charAt(i) ) >= 0) {
    count++;
  }

  //Another one
  if (Character.toString( s.charAt(i) ).matches("[aeiou]")) {
    count++;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I **really** need to work with a `char[]` array and not with a `String` instance, I always use the `Character` class and regular expressions. If you don't know what regular expressions are you should learn them because they are very useful when working with strings. Also, you can practice at [Regexr](http://regexr.com).

For your example I'd use this:

```
char[] data = "programming in Java is fun".toCharArray();
int counter = 0;

for(int i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
    if(Character.toString(data[i]).matches("[aeiou]")){
        counter++;
    }
}

System.out.println(counter); // writes: 8
```

What the if statement does is basically it makes a new `String` instance containing the current character just to be able to use the methods from the `String` class. The method `boolean matches(String regex)` checks whether your string satisfies the conditions given with the `regex` argument.

Answer (score 0):

One more for Java 8:

```
count = str.chars()
           .filter(c -> c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u' )
           .count();
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to do this in using a `List` of `Character` and in [java9](/questions/tagged/java9) could be :

```
List<Character> vowels = List.of('a','e','i','o','u'); // pverloaded convenience factory method 
for(int j=0 ; j < str.length() ; j++) {
    if(vowels.contains(char[j])) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using extension methods.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool Compare(this char c, params char[] ar)
    {
        foreach (var val in ar)
            if (c == val)
                return true;
        return false;
    }
}
// use:

    public static void Main()
    {
        var ans = 'c'.Compare('w', 's', 'c');
    }
```